# Реализация параллельной работы функций программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Для изучения языка взялся за написание импровизированного LAN чата, по нескольким гайдам. Дошло дело до потоков, если я не ошибаюсь, поскольку мне нужно реализовать одновременную прослушку порта и вывод получаемых сообщений плюс возможность отправки сообщений. Вот тут загвоздка, возможно это как обычно какое-то моё недопонимание принципов работы или запутанность кода, но вот что у меня есть:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #Сокет с доменом AF_INET и типом связи SOCK_DGRAM для протокола без установления соединения.
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) #Настройка сокета для прослушивания сокета несколькими приложениями.
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1) #Настройка сокета на послыку широковещательных пакетов.


def recieve_msg(sock): #Функция вывода сообщений
    while True:
        msg = sock.recv(1024)
        playsound('./sounds/income.mp3')
        print(Back.LIGHTGREEN_EX + Fore.BLACK + "Входящее сообщение: ")#Вывод сообщений
        print (Back.BLACK + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + msg.decode().center(20)+"\n")

def send_msg(): #Отправка сообщений
        msg = input(Back.BLACK + Fore.CYAN + "Введите сообщение: ") #Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX
        sock.sendto(msg.encode(),('255.255.255.255', 48700))

def startup(): #Запуск прослушки порта
    sock.bind( ('0.0.0.0', 48700) ) #Привязка сокета к локальному адресу, по адресу 0.0.0.0 или "" прослушиваются все интерфейсы, второе значение - порт.

if True: #Если порт не занят и привязка проходит успешно, выводим приветственные сообщения и запускаем метод получения сообщений recieve_msg() с парметром sock.
    hello = "Welcome to the H.E.V. mark IV protective system."
    print(Back.BLUE + hello.center(120) + "\n")
    print(Back.BLACK + Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + "Чат доступен только в LAN!\n")
    playsound('./sounds/welcome.mp3')
    listen_thread = threading.Thread(target = recieve_msg(sock))
    listen_thread.start()
    send_msg()

else:
    print(Back.RED + Fore.WHITE + "Не удалось подключиться!")
    playsound('./sounds/failure.mp3')

startup()
```

Часть с подключением, привязкой и выводом сообщений работает. При запуске транслятора, который, спамит сообщения, сообщения приходят и выводятся, но вот самому писать сообщения не даёт, возможность написания сообщений реализована в функции send_msg(). Нужны наводки где я не прав.

Comment: Я думаю, у вас всё работает нормально. Просто пока вы печатаете на консоли сообщения успевают заполнить экран и строка ввода оказывается разорванной. Попробуйте в функции `recieve_msg` вывод делать в файл, чтобы экран не затапливало логом сетевых сообщений

Comment: Просто ещё до того как запускаю "транслятор", появляются все сообщения которые выводятся вначале, но не появляется `print()`, не даёт печатать, два абзаца появляется, а печатать не даёт. И я уже по всякому переставлял, по логике вроде как работать должно, но печатать не даёт в консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в конструкторе потока.

Вы написали: `threading.Thread(target = recieve_msg(sock))`
То есть вы сказали интерпретатору Пайтона вызвать функцию `receive_msg(sock)` и результат использовать как параметр `target`

Интерпретатор честно вызывал функцию `receive_msg` и заблокировался.
Ну или впал в бесконечный цикл, если вы стали обстреливать ваш сервер сообщениями.

Правильный вызов конструктора должен выглядеть так:

```
listen_thread = threading.Thread(target = recieve_msg, args=(sock,))
```

Функция, которая вызывается в новом потоке, указывается в параметре `target`. Аргументы, которые нужно передать этой функции при создании потока, указываются в отдельном параметре `args`.

Если вы хотите явно написать вызов функции, то нужно обернуть его в лямбду:

```
listen_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda:recieve_msg(sock))
```

Я проверил в Windows, такой вариант не блокируется, сообщение с клавиатуры ввести можно.

Comment: Действительно работает, вот так вот с ходу и не поймёшь какие аргументы нужно было указывать то ли функции, которую в target описываешь, то ли какие-то аргументы Thread. В любом случае был невнимателен, спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Функция, которая вызывается в новом потоке, указывается в параметре target.
Аргументы, которые нужно передать этой функции при создании потока, указываются в отдельном параметре args. Если вы хотите явно написать вызов функции, то нужно обернуть его в лямбду: `listen_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda:recieve_msg(sock))`